# ListView + Universal Image Loader = очень большие задержки при пролистывании

Tags: java, android, listview

При пролистывании `ListView` наблюдаются очень заметные рывки и паузы. Тестировал на разных устройствах. Миниатюры, которые грузятся при помощи `UniversalImageLoager` весят в среднем 6-10кб.

Как добиться максимальной производительности в списках или что я делаю не так?

Графики (Galaxy S III):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Адаптер для `ListView`:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Zakazchik> implements Filterable {

    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.zakazchik, listZakazchik);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        Integer count = listZakazchik.size();
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.zakazchik, parent, false);
        }

        //Находим заказчика
        Zakazchik currentZakazchik = listZakazchik.get(position);

        TextView tv_item_text_max = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text_max);
        ImageView iv_item_seats_ic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_table_ic);
        TextView tv_item_seats = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_table);
        TextView tv_item_seats_devider = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_seats_devider);
        TextView tv_item_subcategory = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_subcategory);
        TextView item_color_devider = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_status_devider);
        ImageView item_color_ic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_status_ic);
        TextView item_color = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_color);
        tv_item_text_max.setTypeface(Constants.setTypeFace(MainActivity.this, Constants.TYPEFACE_DEFAULT));
        tv_item_seats.setTypeface(Constants.setTypeFace(MainActivity.this, Constants.TYPEFACE_DEFAULT));
        tv_item_seats_devider.setTypeface(Constants.setTypeFace(MainActivity.this, Constants.TYPEFACE_DEFAULT));
        tv_item_subcategory.setTypeface(Constants.setTypeFace(MainActivity.this, Constants.TYPEFACE_DEFAULT));
        item_color_devider.setTypeface(Constants.setTypeFace(MainActivity.this, Constants.TYPEFACE_DEFAULT));
        item_color.setTypeface(Constants.setTypeFace(MainActivity.this, Constants.TYPEFACE_DEFAULT));

        ImageView item_crown = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_crown_icon);
        item_crown.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        //Если есть данные о количестве мест (!=0) - показать их
        if (currentZakazchik.getCategory() == 19){
            tv_item_seats_devider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            iv_item_seats_ic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv_item_seats.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv_item_text_max.setText("ср.чек");
            iv_item_seats_ic.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_seat));
            tv_item_seats.setText(String.valueOf(currentZakazchik.getSeats()));
        }

        if (currentZakazchik.getCategory() == 20){
            tv_item_seats_devider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            iv_item_seats_ic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv_item_seats.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv_item_text_max.setText("min");
            iv_item_seats_ic.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_seats_avto));
            tv_item_seats.setText(String.valueOf(currentZakazchik.getSeats()));
        }

        if (currentZakazchik.getSeats() != 0 && currentZakazchik.getColor().length() > 3){
            tv_item_seats_devider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            iv_item_seats_ic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv_item_seats.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv_item_text_max.setText("min");
            iv_item_seats_ic.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_seats_avto));
            tv_item_seats.setText(String.valueOf(currentZakazchik.getSeats()));
            item_color_devider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            item_color_ic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            item_color.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            item_color_ic.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_color));
            item_color.setText(String.valueOf(currentZakazchik.getColor()));
        }

        //Показываем имя
        TextView nameText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        nameText.setText(currentZakazchik.getName());
        nameText.setTypeface(Constants.setTypeFace(MainActivity.this, Constants.TYPEFACE_DEFAULT));

        //Показываем аватарку
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_photo);

        imageLoader.displayImage(currentZakazchik.getAvatarUrl(), imageView);

        //Показываем рейтинг заказчика
        TextView ratingText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_guests);
        ratingText.setText("" + currentZakazchik.getRating());
        ratingText.setTypeface(Constants.setTypeFace(MainActivity.this, Constants.TYPEFACE_DEFAULT));

        //Показываем минимальную стоимость услуг заказчика
        TextView minPriceText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_mincost);
        minPriceText.setTypeface(Constants.setTypeFace(MainActivity.this, Constants.TYPEFACE_DEFAULT));

        if (currentZakazchik.getMinCost() == 0) {
            minPriceText.setText("-");
            //minCost = "-"; //Показываем "-" вместо стоимости (если 0)
        } else {
            minPriceText.setText("" + currentZakazchik.getMinCost() + "р");
            //minCost = "" + currentZakazchik.getMinCost() + "р"; //Показываем мин. стоимость
        }

        //Показываем название подкатегории
        if (currentZakazchik.getZRating() <= 6) {
            tv_item_subcategory.setText(currentZakazchik.getSubcategory());
            tv_item_subcategory.setTypeface(Constants.setTypeFace(MainActivity.this, Constants.TYPEFACE_LIGHT_ITALIC));
        } else {
            tv_item_subcategory.setText("");
        }

        if (currentZakazchik.getZRating() <= 5 && currentZakazchik.getZRating() >= 1) {
            item_crown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ratingText.setText("PRO");
        }

        RelativeLayout back = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.zakazchik_tab4_contacts);

        int serverDateInt = Integer.parseInt(currentZakazchik.getMarkedEndDate().replace("-",""));
        if (serverDateInt >= currentDateInt) {
            back.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.list_mark));
        } else {
            back.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        }

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
                if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                    result.values = allZakazchik;
                    result.count = allZakazchik.size();
                }else{
                    filteredList = new ArrayList<Zakazchik>();
                    for(Zakazchik z: allZakazchik){
                        if(z.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                            filteredList.add(z);
                        else if (z.getSubcategory().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                            filteredList.add(z);
                        else if ((z.getColor().length() > 0 && z.getColor().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())))
                            filteredList.add(z);
                    }
                    result.values = filteredList;
                    result.count = filteredList.size();
                }
                return result;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                RelativeLayout rl_nothing_found = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_nothing_found);
                if (results.count == 0){
                    rl_nothing_found.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    rl_nothing_found.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                listZakazchik = (ArrayList<Zakazchik>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Конфигурация Universal Image Loader:

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_image)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .memoryCacheExtraOptions(480, 800) // default = device screen dimensions
            .diskCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, null)
            .threadPoolSize(5) // default
            .threadPriority(4) // default
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO) // default
            //.denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .memoryCacheSizePercentage(13) // default
            .diskCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // default
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options) // default
            .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

Comment: 1. используйте паттерн `ViewHolder`, или вообще `RecyclerView`. 2. Можете попробовать использовать не `UIL`, а `Picasso` http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: 3. Избавиться от этой жути setTypeface(Constants.setTypeFace(MainActivity.this, Constants.TYPEFACE_DEFAULT));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализируйте паттерн ViewHolder, пример:

```
    public class ViewHolder{
        private TextView textView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textView.setText("Hello");
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Применил, но рывки остались.
Сильнее всего на это влияет применение своих шрифтов для множества TextView, менее - загрузка ImageLoader'ом картинок.
Как еще можно оптимизировать эти два пункта?

Comment: Когда вы инициализируете ваши TextView в ViewHolder меняйте шрифт, тогда setTypeFace будет срабатывать только один раз для каждего View.

Comment: Отлично, ViewHolder и шрифты в нем же значительно улучшили сенсу скрола. Теперь фризит чуть-чуть когда картинки в UIL грузятся первый раз в кэш. Какой параметр опции UIL отвечает за плавность подгрузки картинок не в UI-фреде?

Comment: Я для подгрузки изображений использую Picasso, а не UIL, по этому извините я вам ничем в этом вопросе помочь немогу(. Picasso у меня летает как самолёт, я разрабатываю приложения под интернет магазины и у меня даже при плохом интернете Picasso работал отлично.